# Is it possible to create view with list of objects and forms to update?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to solve my problem with django for last 2 days, I've searched many reddit posts/ git repos / stack questions and I've achieved nothing.

I'm learning django and doing a project to help me in my current job.

My goal is to make detail view of model "Partner" where I'll list all it's "PartnerMugs"

```
models.py

class Partner(models.Model):
    partner_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["partner_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.partner_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("partners:detail", kwargs={"pk":self.pk})

class PartnerMug(models.Model):
    partner     = models.ForeignKey('Partner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pattern     = models.ForeignKey('patterns.Pattern', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xs_amount   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    xl_amount   = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["partner"]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.partner) + " " + str(self.pattern)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('partners:detail', args=[self.partner.pk])
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to put form for each "PartnerMug" object in my list. I tried to do something with inlineformset_factory, but I didn't find the way how to put it in my for loop.

```
form.py

class PartnerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = ['partner_name']

class MugAmountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PartnerMug
        fields = ['xs_amount','xl_amount',]

MugAmountFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Partner, PartnerMug, form=MugAmountForm, extra=0)
```

Updated view.py:

```
view.py

def par_detail_view(request, pk=None):
    obj = Partner(pk=pk)

    mugsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Partner, PartnerMug, form=MugAmountForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == "POST":
        mugsFormSet = mugsFormSet(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if mugsFormSet.is_valid():
            mugsFormSet.save()
    else:
        mugsFormSet = mugsFormSet(instance=obj)

    return render(request, 'partners/pattern_function.html', {
    'mugsFormSet':mugsFormSet,
    'obj':obj
})
```

Updated template.html

```
template.html

    {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for partner_mugs in obj.partnermug_set.all  %}
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                {% if partner_mugs.pattern.pattern_thumbnail %}
                    <img src="{{ partner_mugs.pattern.pattern_thumbnail.url }}" class="thumbnail">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4>pattern:{{ partner_mugs.pattern }}</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                            <p>small: {{ partner_mugs.xs_amount }}</p>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <p>large: {{ partner_mugs.xl_amount }}</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>       
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profile</legend>
        <br>
{{ formset.management_form }}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">

{% for form in mugsFormSet.forms %}



 {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle "row1" "row2" %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr> 
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn" />  
</fieldset>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'd like to put form for xs_amount in div :

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
     <p>Small: {{ partner_mugs.xs_amount }}</p>                            
</div>
```

And xl_amount in:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
     <p>Large: {{ partner_mugs.xl_amount }}</p>                            
 </div>
```

Both forms under the values.
Is it even possible to loop through objects and it's forms in the same time? All forms should be submited by one button in the same time.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaVGx.png)

Comment: May I suggest another approach? Without using ModelFormMixin and DetailView class? (I hardly use them, preferring a more manual approach)

Comment: I will appreciate any suggestions :) More manual approach will be better to learn more of django.

Comment: I pasted an example of formset usage. Let me know if that helps you understand how to use them!

Answer (score 0):

On your `views.py` create a function linked to your url.

I am not able to re-write your code, but I think you may find my example useful:

```
def profile(request):
    user = request.user     
    userform=UserForm(instance=user)

    addressFormSet=inlineformset_factory(User, ProfileAddress, form=ProfileAddressForm ,can_delete=False,extra=1)


if request.method == "POST":
    userform=UserForm(request.POST,instance=user)
    addressFormSet = addressFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)


    if userform.is_valid() and addressFormSet.is_valid() a:
       userform.save()
       addressFormSet.save()


else:
    addressFormSet = addressFormSet(instance=user.profile)


return render(request, 'template.html', {
    'userform':userform,
    'addressFormSet':addressFormSet,
})
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Profile</legend>

                {% include "form_snippet.html" with form=userform %}
                {% include "inlineTableForm.html" with formset=addressFormSet %}
            <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn" />  
</fieldset>
    </form>
```

**inlineTableForm.html**

```
      <br>
{{ formset.management_form }}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">

{% for form in formset.forms %}



 {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle "row1" "row2" %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr> 
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! For the first time my formset is actually working. 
I don't want to abuse your patiece, but can You give me any tip how to "deconstruct" formset and use it as I described it in my question? 
I would like to iterate thorugh my objects and for each object in one row put all of it's info ('pattern','partner','xs_amount' etc.) and forms to change it's 'xs_amount', and 'xl_amount'.(One iteration = one object info and one form to change it)

Comment: @A.Bartecki I am not sure I understand, but lets go step by step! Now you are able to see your Partner and PartnerMug data on your webpage?

Comment: I have added to my context 'obj':obj which is "obj = Partner(pk=pk)" And I am able to iterate using  "{% for partner_mugs in obj.partnermug_set.all  %}"
And for now i have a list of all PartnerMugs of my Partner, and formset under the list

Comment: Please update the main question with the new code, and your html result (screenshot is fine)

Comment: I've edited main question. Sorry it took so long. Screenshot of my result is at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my problem. I used @Walucas inlineformset_factory and function view. And in "inlineTableForm.html" I used "form.instance" to get values of my objects:

```
<br>
{{ formset.management_form }}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Thumbnail:</th>
        <th>Pattern:</th>
        <th>xs:</th>
        <th>xl:</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  {% endif %}
    <tr class="{% cycle "row1" "row2" %}">
      <td><img src="{{ form.instance.pattern.pattern_thumbnail.url }}"     class="thumbnail"></td>
      <td>{{ form.instance.pattern }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.xs_amount }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.xl_amount }}</td>
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
          {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}
        {{ form.errors.as_ul }}

    </tr>


{% endfor %}
```

Now i have rows with each object thumbnail , pattern name and forms to change amount.
".instance" in formset was the key to understand all of this